# forms to generate html page

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I don't consider myself a webdeveloper but I successfully been able to build a rwd landing page by using bootstrap and jquery.

Now I need some forms it order to save the content in a db and then to generate the html file. This html file will be available online.

I know some PHP and I might be able to build a dummy solution for my problem. I ask for your advice, because I assume that there are some open source solutions or CMS ready to use and to learn from. Can you give me some names?

Please don't consider this question as being too broad. I'm looking for a general solution as a starting point.

Comment: There will be many of us who consider the question too broad, because it is too broad. There will be 1000s of answers. You could always learn a PHP framework, google for that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems#PHP

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see what and how to ask